# compare openxml files

Tags: c#, web, compare, openxml

I'm developping a tool to manage some documents with versioncontrol. I have a windows client who is comparing 2 documents (previous version with current version) to see the differences between both documents. That is working fine (i'm using the interop dll's of microsoft).

I also have a web client where i want to do the same thing, but i don't want to install office on the server.
In my web client i only alow openxml files (docx, xlsx) because i can read and update versiondate in the document without having office installed.
Is there some tool where i can compare 2 openxml files with and show differences in a new document? (i already searched on it and there is some tool openxmldiff, but the results i get are some xml files and don't know how to combine them in a new document.
Any help?

Answer (score 1):

You may want to take a look at OpenXml Powertools:
http://powertools.codeplex.com/

It has a DocumentComparer Class.
At least it is maybe a starting point.

Answer (score 0):

The [Open XML SDK 2.0 Productivity tool](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=5124) has a compare files option that will diff the two open xml files and show you the differences.